# Adding Eclipse project into Processing 3

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I am using Processing 3 (https://processing.org) and I have followed the "Processing in Eclipse" tutorial which works fine.

What I am trying to do is import my Eclipse project back into Processing 3 so I can get a .PDE file for web browsers. How can I do this?

Porting to Eclipse is fine and simple but I am not sure how to add the project back into Processing.

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I didn't, I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by getting a `.pde` file for web browsers, but here is how you would use your Eclipse project as a library in Processing:

**Step 1:** Export your project as a `.jar` file from Eclipse.

**Step 2:** Drag the generated `.jar` file onto the Processing editor. You can now use your project in that Processing sketch.

If you want to use the library in multiple sketches without dragging the `.jar` file every time, check out [this article](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/How-to-Install-a-Contributed-Library) on manually installing libraries.

Comment: The processing.js library loads your .pde file into a html5 canvas so that's what I wanted to do with my current app that uses swing.

Comment: @SurajKumar What you're describing will **not** work. You can't put arbitrary Java into a `Processing.js` sketch. It has to be Java that has been ported over to JavaScript, so it can be translated. Swing is not one of those things.